# Como prevenir que pseudo-elemento (::before ou ::after) dentro de uma tag <a> seja clicável?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, link

Existe alguma forma de evitar que o *pseudo-elemento* `::after` ou `::before` de um link `<a>` se torne parte do próprio link?

Minha ideia era usar um `::after` em uma tag de link `<a>`, esse `::after` seria usado para substituir o conteúdo de dentro do próprio link que até certo momento não quero mostrar ao usuário, porém percebi que esse `::after` se torna parte do próprio link, só que eu não quero que esse *pseudo-elemento* tenha link

Nesse exemplo eu coloquei um texto substituindo o nome do link, o texto que está dentro ta tag `<a>`, porém esse texto continua clicável.

```css
.link {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.link:after {
  visibility: visible;
  content: 'Texto visível';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" class="link">google</a>
<a href="www.yahoo.com" class="link">yahoo</a>
<a href="www.terra.com">link real</a>
<a href="www.uol.com" class="link">uol</a>
```

Como evitar esse problema do `::after` do link se tornar clicável?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar o `pointer-events: none;`

Veja:

```css
.link {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.link:after {
  visibility: visible;
  content: 'Texto visível';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" class="link">google</a>
<a href="www.yahoo.com" class="link">yahoo</a>
<a href="www.terra.com">link real</a>
<a href="www.uol.com" class="link">uol</a>
```

A propriedade faz com que o elemento não tenha iteração com o mouse.
Eu costumo usar em casos onde eu preciso, por exemplo, estilizar um `select` com uma setinha personalizada, porém essa setinha não pode ser "clicável".

Ele é como um equivalente à `event.preventDefault()` do Javascript.